# Redirecting base request to specific jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I am new to Spring and I know that is a newbie question, but I didn't find solution on web. 
I am developing application and I have to redirect all requests from base to index (for example mysite.com/ has to be redirected to mysite.com/index).

I am already finished this according to this:
I am created BaseController class and declared mapping for /.

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Index.
 *
 * @return the string
 * @throws IOException 
 */
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/")
public void index(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.sendRedirect("/index");
}
```

It works well for request in format: `mysite.com/appname/` and it redirects to `mysite.com/index`, but in that case I get 404 because it works with `mysite.com/appname/index`.

I know that this is related to setup, but I don't know what.
Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Note that, all is functional on `mysite.com/appname/index` but I need following format: `mysite.com/index`.
If you need some additional info, I will post it.
Can anybody help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: Is `/appname` your context path?

Comment: I haven't defined context path. I'll check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but you stated

> Note that, all is functional on `mysite.com/appname/index` but I need
>   following format: `mysite.com/index`.

The `/appname` part is not a Spring configuration. It is a Servlet container configuration and is known as the context path.

Depending on your Servlet container, you can change the context path of each of your web applications. In this case, you would set it to `/`.

For Tomcat, you'll find how to change it [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).